# PepperFlash Problems

Tags: firefox, flash

I need help with a 'Flash' issue on my 32 bit Ubuntu 15.10. While I am not a complete novice to Linux I am no means an expert, and it appears I need one that can talk a proverbial five year old through this situation that I now face. Usually I have little to no problems using the forums to help this old man figure out how to do whatever on Linux that I have a question about. But that path seems to have taken wrong turn in this case, and I have gotten it really screwed up now.

I could try to recreate and describe all that I have done to try to fix this but I know I would leave some parts of it out. So basically I need to know how to fix it after an idiot (myself) has totally FUBARED it. Flash doesn't work on any browser now. I figure that it totally needs to be removed and reinstalled, however the apt-get remove process appears to work in the CLI but when I reinstall afterwards I have the same nonfunctioning mess.

This all started when I was trying to add flash functionality to a new browser that I had installed (Vivaldi). Flash was working fine in Mozilla at the time. But now I get a big 'X' in the window as a placeholder where flash needs to run and a prompt that says "Failed to load libpepflashplayer.so" in the Vivaldi browser, and in Mozilla I get the same, except it also adds "Freshwrapper is a translation layer which needs PPAPI plugin backend. Ensure your system have "libpepflashplayer.so" available. Paths tried:"... and then it lists 13 paths where it looked for the .so file in question.

I cannot find the file on this computer anywhere even after uninstalling and reinstalling the pepperflash plugin (by both the software center and the CLI)...

After several hours reading and trying to fix this I decided it was time to seek help from the community. I just want to say that the community's time and patience with an old heathen like me is greatly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Comment not answer.  I have the same problem described above after trying to add flash to Chromium, via advice(?) found in the community.  Now I don't have flash on either Firefox or Chromium.  I would also appreciate help for a path forward.